# CSS: Trouble with internal links and equal column heights [jsfiddle]

Tags: css

I am using a CSS only solution to get the appearance of equal height columns:

```
.equal-height-row {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.equal-height-col {
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
}
```

So that when I do this:

```
<div class="equal-height-row">

    <div class="left equal-height-col">
      <p>This is the first column.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="right equal-height-col">
      <p>This is the second column.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae optio, tenetur ipsa. Veritatis, consequatur? Optio totam, hic voluptate eos magnam aspernatur. Accusamus similique aperiam, soluta, omnis corporis reprehenderit illum quasi.</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

...both columns appear to be the same height. The problem I am running into is when an internal anchor link is visited, everything above it is being cut off of the page.

**Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ctkL4yx/**

Notice just scrolling the HTML, it looks great. Now, try clicking a link and notice all the content above it gets chopped off.

How can I correct this?

```
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
.right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
.equal-height-row {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.equal-height-col {
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
}


<p>
<a href="#first">First</a><br />
<a href="#second">Second</a>
</p>
<div class="equal-height-row">

<div class="left equal-height-col">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae optio, tenetur ipsa. Veritatis, consequatur? Optio totam, hic voluptate eos magnam aspernatur. Accusamus similique aperiam, soluta, omnis corporis reprehenderit illum quasi.
</p>
</div>

<div class="right equal-height-col">
<p id="first">FIRST ANCHOR<br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae optio, tenetur ipsa. Veritatis, consequatur? Optio totam, hic voluptate eos magnam aspernatur. Accusamus similique aperiam, soluta, omnis corporis reprehenderit illum quasi.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae optio, tenetur ipsa. Veritatis, consequatur? Optio totam, hic voluptate eos magnam aspernatur. Accusamus similique aperiam, soluta, omnis corporis reprehenderit illum quasi.
</p>
<p id="second">SECOND ANCHOR<br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae optio, tenetur ipsa. Veritatis, consequatur? Optio totam, hic voluptate eos magnam aspernatur. Accusamus similique aperiam, soluta, omnis corporis reprehenderit illum quasi.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae optio, tenetur ipsa. Veritatis, consequatur? Optio totam, hic voluptate eos magnam aspernatur. Accusamus similique aperiam, soluta, omnis corporis reprehenderit illum quasi.
</p>
</div>

</div><!--/.equal-height-row-->
```

Comment: Not sure how to correct this, but since the divs are like 10k pixels tall, when the anchor is clicked, the div internally scrolls. Since overflow hidden is used, you cannot see the scroll, nor the overflow, and as a result the content is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` cuts off anything beyond the certain part of the element, and when you jump to a link, you jump to that line of the text. There's no natively CSS solution for the default link behavior to change, alas. Instead, you want `overflow: scroll` instead on your `.equal-height-row` class to preserve the height without any content being cut off.

Or you could just use flexbox, and give the `.equal-height-row` a `display` property of `flex` to establish it as your flex container. With flexbox, you won't need the `padding-bottom: 99999px;margin-bottom: -99999px;` hack for establishing equal column height, so your CSS would be:

```
.left {
  background: red;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
}
.equal-height-row {
display: flex;
}
```